# Salesforce MobileSDK: The Rest API is not enabled for this Organization

Tags: android, salesforce

I am trying to use Salesforce Mobile SDK for native Android.
Requirement:

> 1. Allow any user with Salesforce account to login
> 2. Fetch his/her contacts list
> 3. Fetch particular contact details

**Please let me know if those are not part of the Mobile SDK.**

I followed https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android:

> 1. Cloned it
> 2. Installed NPM and installed the required submodules
> 3. Created a new Android application using native forcedroid
> 4. Changed the `bootconfig.xml` values with the values of my connected app.

It logs in fine but when I try to fetch the contacts, it says:

> The Rest API is not enabled for this Organization

[image]

The login response seems to be fine. Client object json credentials:

```
{
  "clientId": "*******",
  "loginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "identityUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/99VVHJHGF5688/00548000003yOKeAAM",
  "instanceUrl": "https://ap2.salesforce.com",
  "userId": "**********",
  "orgId": "*********",
  "communityUrl": null,
  "refreshToken": "*************",
  "accessToken": "************",
  "communityId": null,
  "userAgent": "SalesforceMobileSDK/4.3.0 android mobile/7.0 (Nexus 6P) SFTest/1.0 Native uid_32aea9bdde1b8b7e"
}
```

**EDIT 1 :** Code to get Contacts list:

```
public void onFetchContactsClick(View v) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    sendRequest("SELECT Name FROM Contact");
}

private void sendRequest(String soql) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    RestRequest restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForQuery(ApiVersionStrings.getVersionNumber(this), soql);

    client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, final RestResponse result) {
            result.consumeQuietly(); // consume before going back to main thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        listAdapter.clear();
                        JSONArray records = result.asJSONObject().getJSONArray("records");
                        for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                            listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        onError(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final Exception exception) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.this.getString(SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().getSalesforceR().stringGenericError(), exception.toString()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 2 :** Some more findings:

> I think it has to do with my account/connected app settings. Because
>   when I signedup using https://developer.salesforce.com/signup and used
>   the `username` it works fine. Here again if I used the `email` instead
>   it shows the same error of API not enabled. I created multiple
>   `username`s using the same `email` and the signup form, they all work
>   fine, but not the email.
>
> BTW I am currently using a trial version of salesforce.

Comment: I think you made JsonArrayRequest to API.

Comment: @Bansal The request code is generated by the SDK so it is standard.

Comment: Perhaps try one of Salesforce's Android native sample apps e.g. https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/tree/master/native/NativeSampleApps/RestExplorer

Comment: @CliveSeebregts please check Edit-2

Answer (score 1):

regular trial accounts are for Professional Edition, which doesn't include API access, which is the error you're getting. You need to use an account with API access such as a free developer edition account, or an enterprise edition account.

Comment: So if my https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp account is paid and have a connected app, on integration with my Android app, any user with a salesforce account can login and access the APIs? I just want to make sure that it need not be a developer account.

Comment: Are you building an app for your companies salesforce users, or are you building an app for other companies salesforce users [i.e. a partner or ISV situation]?

Comment: **Not** for `my company users`. Ideally any salesforce user of any company should be able to login through my Android app and use the APIs.

Comment: sign up for a developer edition account, create your connected app settings there, and you're good to go.

Comment: That is where I started. Please check **EDIT 2**.

Comment: As my answer states, not all account types have API access, so there will be some user accounts that can't use your app. Also you can't login with email address, only usernames.